# The Dirichlet Distribution

Tags: self-study, distributions, mathematical-statistics

I'm reading a online book titled Mathematical Statistics Old School which can be found [here](http://www.istics.net/pdfs/mathstat.pdf).

In the section about the Dirichlet Distribution (which begins on page 63 if you would like to look) it says to let 
$X_1, \ldots, X_K$ be independent random variables, where $X_k \sim Gamma(\alpha_k, 1)$.

Then the $K-1$ vector $\underline{Y}$ defined by 
$$Y_k = \frac{X_k}{X_1 + \cdots + X_K} , k = 1,\ldots, K-1$$
has a Dirichlet distribution. So $\underline{Y} \sim Dirichlet(\alpha_1, \ldots, \alpha_K)$. It is noted that $Y_1 + \cdots +Y_K = 1$.

The text says the following two things, which I am having trouble understanding:

> 1. The marginals $Y_k \sim Beta(\alpha_k, 1- \alpha_k)$
> 2. If $X_k \sim Gamma(\alpha_k, \lambda)$, then the definition is the same.

For my first issue, I thought it would be that $$Y_k \sim Beta(\alpha_k, \sum_{i\neq k} \alpha_i)$$ because if $X_1 \sim Gamma(\alpha_1, \lambda)$ and $X_2 \sim Gamma(\alpha_2, \lambda)$ then $$\frac{X_1}{X_1 + X_2} \sim Beta(\alpha_1, \alpha_2).$$

I think clearing this issue up would help me see that if $X_k \sim Gamma(\alpha_k, \lambda)$, then the definition is the same.

**EDIT Jan 24 '17:** I'm not really sure how my question is a duplication of [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/244996/89012). But I am glad it was pointed out . As pointed out by Xi'an in the comments, my confusion is due to a typo in the text I am reading.

I think it would be more accurate to mark this question as answered instead of as duplicate.

Comment: You are right and the book is wrong: the correct result is for instance in Devroye's [Non-Uniform Random Variate Generation](http://amzn.to/2kmdRn9).

Comment: The second issue is straightforward: if $X_k \sim \text{G}(\alpha_k, \lambda)$, then $\lambda X_k \sim \text{G}(\alpha_k, 1)$. You only need to multiply numerator and denominator by $\lambda$ to get back to the original definition. The scale factor has no impact on the ratio.