# Marginal density of dirichlet distribution

Tags: marginal-distribution, integral, dirichlet-distribution, constraint

I'm studying [BRML](http://web4.cs.ucl.ac.uk/staff/D.Barber/pmwiki/pmwiki.php?n=BrmlOnline).

In this book, a Dirichlet distribution is defined as
$$
p(\alpha | u) = \frac{\Gamma(\sum_{q=1}^Q u_q)}{\prod_{q=1}^Q \Gamma(u_q)} \delta_0 \left( \sum_{q=1}^{Q} \alpha_q - 1 \right) \prod_{q=1}^{Q} \alpha_q^{u_q - 1} \mathbb{I}[\alpha_q \geq 0],
$$ where $\delta$ is Dirac's delta, and [Exercise 8.7](http://web4.cs.ucl.ac.uk/staff/D.Barber/pmwiki/pmwiki.php?n=BrmlOnline) is to show that $$\displaystyle\int_{\theta_j} \textrm{Dirichlet}(\theta | u) = \textrm{Dirichlet}(\theta_{\backslash j} | u_{\backslash j})$$

Since we integrate on $\theta_j$, Dirac's delta term becomes function of $\theta_j$, which is
$$\delta_0 \left( \theta_j - (1-\sum_{i\neq j} \theta_i) \right)$$ and we can push out irrelevant terms to outside of integral, then it becomes
$$
\frac{\Gamma(\sum_{q=1}^Q u_q)}{\prod_{q=1}^Q \Gamma(u_q)}  \prod_{q \neq j}^{Q} \theta_q^{u_q - 1} \mathbb{I}[\theta_q \geq 0] \int \delta\left(\theta_j - (1 - \sum_{i\neq j}\theta_i )\right) \theta_j^{u_j - 1} \mathbb{I}[\theta_j \geq 0]
$$
With the definition of Dirac's delta, I got
$$
\frac{\Gamma(\sum_{q=1}^Q u_q)}{\prod_{q=1}^Q \Gamma(u_q)}  \left(\prod_{q \neq j}^{Q} \theta_q^{u_q - 1} \mathbb{I}[\theta_q \geq 0] \right) (1-\sum_{i\neq j} \theta_i)_j^{u_j - 1} \mathbb{I}\left[1-\sum_{i\neq j}\theta_i \geq 0\right]
$$
But I don't know how it can be
$\displaystyle\textrm{Dirichlet}(\theta_{\backslash j} | u_{\backslash j}) = \frac{\Gamma(\sum_{q\neq j}^Q u_q)}{\prod_{q \neq j}^Q \Gamma(u_q)} \delta \left( \sum_{q\neq j}^{Q} \theta_q - 1 \right) \prod_{q\neq j}^{Q} \theta_q^{u_q - 1} \mathbb{I}[\theta_q \geq 0]$

I searched internet a couple of minutes, then I found [some relevant answers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/543764/let-x-y-have-a-dirichlet-distribution-with-paramters-alpha-1-alpha-2-al)
and further ones like [this one](http://web4.cs.ucl.ac.uk/staff/D.Barber/pmwiki/pmwiki.php?n=BrmlOnline) and [that one](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/319292/find-marginal-distribution-of-k-variate-dirichlet)

But I cannot apply them to my problem due to different notations and definition.
Especially, I want to know how to derive dirac delta term.

Comment: Forget about Dirac's deltas, which are needlessly confusing, and consider this density to be defined over the simplex of $\mathbb R^{Q-1}$, that is, in terms of the vector $(\alpha_1,\ldots, \alpha_{Q-1})$, replacing $\alpha_Q$ by$$1-\sum_{i<Q}\alpha_i$$

Comment: This is the representation adopted on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_distribution) and it is consistent with the $Q=2$ case of the Beta distribution.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Obviously, your notation seems more standard than dirac delta notation.